# How to change Font settings for whole Phone using an Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts

I want to create a app, which will change the font size for whole phone.
Like (settings->font size and style)
I want develop an app to do this.
is there any way to change font size settings?

Comment: I think this is not possible, working with Android for 6 years and never heard of possibility to change global setting from single app.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that change font setting for whole phone, android don't have this permission